# WiFi Data transfer problem with Nex 6

Tags: troubleshooting, sony-nex, file-transfer

I have a Nex 6, although I managed to use the photo transfers from my camera to my computer initially, I am having trouble doing this process now.  My camera is giving me the message "Connected to the access point.  Cannot connect to the computer to be saved". 
Can someone help please!

Comment: What troubleshooting have you tried? It sounds like you are using the Sony downloader software, if that is true please state that explicitly in your question. Is your computer a laptop? Desktop? Mac? PC? No one can help you with the little bit of info you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds more of a technical problem unrelated to actual photography, so places like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) might yield more/better answers.

Having said that, my initial guesses would be that the target computer is not connected to the same WiFi, or not reachable from there due to a firewall, for example. Another thought might be that whichever software running on the target computer, that accepts the images, might be switched off — I don't know if the Nex 6 uses some form of service, or a program you have to start manually, or uses normal windows file shares. In case of the latter, it might be removed, or the access rights revoked.

I wish I could give more specific information, but not having experience with that WiFi transfer system there, I cannot "home in" better on the causes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if it's a Mac or PC, and this question is old. But if someone with a Mac comes looking for an answer, here is one possibility:

When you download pictures using the included Sony Downloader software for the NEX when it is done it shows a little popup with some buttons that will do things like open the folder where your photos were downloaded to. You have to close that popup before another download can happen.